# reading files from java?

Tags: java, file

I have an assignment where I have to make a simple banking application. i need to store the customers information in a file with first and last name,customer id and balance. i then need to create a menu option to check balance,withdraw,deposit and quit. The problem i am currently having is trying to show the balance when they user wants to check balance. balance is on the forth line of my file and i am not sure how to only show the fourth line and then be able to use that number to add or subtract a number. I am trying to do this in case 1 in the switch statement. Any hints would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.*;
public class bank {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        String fileName; // stores the name of the file
        String bankCustomer; // used to display the customers bank information
        int menuOption = 0; // allows the user to enter a number so they can select what they want to do

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );

        // enter the file name to see customer information
        System.out.print("enter file name ");
        fileName = keyboard.nextLine();

        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        // read customer information from file i need this
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            bankCustomer = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(bankCustomer);
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the number for the following:\n 1) Balance \n 2) Deposit + \n 3) Withdrawal \n 4) Quit ");

        menuOption = keyboard.nextInt();

        switch (menuOption) {
            case 1:
                // need to show balance how do i do that?
                while (inputFile.hasNext()) {

                    bankCustomer = inputFile.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(bankCustomer);
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One way is to read all the lines from the `Scanner`object and convert it into a List (ArrayList) or String Array. That is each item in the Array or List corresponds to a line of the file.

The index of the list or array will then provide with the contents of the that particular file.

=============================================================================

Ok based on your comment, now that you still have not learn Arrays you can do it the way your reading your bank Customer name

```
String bankCustomer = inputFile.nextLine();

//Assuming second line contains account number
String bankAccountNumber = inputFile.nextLine();

// Assuming third line contains account type.
String bankAccountType = inputFile.nextLine();

// Fourth line has your account balance
String bankAccountBalanceStr = inputFile.nextLine();

double bankAccountBalance = 0d;
if(null != bankAccountBalanceStr && 0 > bankAccountBalanceStr.length()){
     bankAccountBalance = Double.parseDouble(bankAccountBalanceStr);
}
```

Of course the answer is just indicative and does not do all the null checks and assumes the file format is exactly as you have told.

Comment: we have not covered arrays yet in class so i am looking for a way to do it without arrays

Comment: @RishiDholliwar  Have you covered creating classes? If so, create `User` class with all these fields and populate it.

Comment: how do i implement this in my code? do i put it inside while (inputFile.hasNext()) loop? and then if i want to display the account balance do i simply use System.out.println(bankAccountBalance); to display it? i tried it and it didnt work. not sure what to do?

Comment: like how do i get the first line of my file to equal bankCustomer

Comment: change `while(inputFile.hasNext())` to `if(inputFile.hasNext())`. And check 'if(inputFile.hasNext())' before each of the `nextLine()` calls.

Example:

`String bankCustomer = null;
if(inputFile.hasNext()){
 bankCustomer = inputFile.nextLine();
}`

But if you are absolutely sure that the file format is always going to be correct and is always going to have lines that you are looking for then you can skip the if checks.

Comment: Just by typing:
`String bankCustomer = inputFile.nextLine();` you get the first line into `bankCustomer`.
After this if you type:
`String bankAccountType = inputFile.nextLine();` you get the second line into `bankAccountType`.

Comment: Thanks i got it working :) only problem is i had to add an extra line of text to my file as it wouldn't read the last line.

Comment: @RishiDholliwar - The discussion being carried out in these comments would be better served by meeting with your Professor or TA (Teaching Assistant). As it is, you've solved your immediate problem, but (1) do you understand the solution? and (2) have you learned how to solve problems on your own? Your statement _"i had to add an extra line of text to my file"_ indicates that you don't really understand what you've done.

Comment: yes i understand. i was able to complete the rest  of the assignment

Comment: that bit i was not sure about but i will ask my teacher about it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply read and ignore the first three lines, by doing something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    inputFile.nextLine();
```

and then reading the fourth line as an integer with the Integer.parseInt () method.

```
int total = Integer.parseInt (inputFile.nextLine ());
```

Note that in both snippets error and exception handling was omitted.

Comment: i pasted this in my switch statement and then used System.out.println(bankCustomer); and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Without recreating your data and code, it appear that you are reading the entire line of data to bankcustomer.  If your data file structure IS  comma-delimited, you could then split the line into components.  Define a data class

```
public static class customer {
   public String first;
   public String last;
   public String customer_i;
   public double balance:
```

}

Once you have the line translated into the data class, you can reference each by:

```
balance = customer.balance.  etc.
```

This is approximate but I hope it helps.

Comment: Im still not sure how to implement this in my code. how do i get the first line to be put in first or the last line to be in balance.

Answer (score 0):

You can either read 3 lines and not save their values, 
or search each line for a keyword:

```
int balance;
if(!bankCustomer.indexOf("balance") != -1)
{
    balance = Integer.parseInt(bankCustomer);
}
```